# Цветные полосы Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

Что означают эти цветные полосы?Вроде ошибок нету в этих местах.

Пример:

```
    public static bool ShowDebug { get; set; }
    public static bool ShowErrors { get; set; }
    public static bool ShowException { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это полосы самой студии, означают изменение теста.

- Желтая - текст изменен, но не был сохранен.
- Зеленая - текст изменен и сохранен.

Вы можете посмотреть все цвета в настройках студии:

- `Средства (Tools)` - `Параметры (Options)` - `Окружение (Environment)` - `Шрифты и цвета (Fonts and Colors)`.
- Смотрим нужный цвет. В данном случае цвет берется из `Отслеживание изменений перед сохранением` и `Отслеживание изменений после сохранения`.

Comment: спасибо.Думал сломал проект

Comment: @Сергей Не бойтесь экспериментировать! Ну а вообще, если бы вы "сломали" проект, то вам на это явно намекнула бы студия с выводом подробной ошибки. P.S. Если ответ оказался верным - не забудьте поставить "галку" сбоку.